# The workflow about using cross_val_score to predict

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to confirm about the workflow of using `cross_val_score` in sklearn to predict.

1. Initialize the estimattor like using Logistic regression model like this:

   ```
   model = LogisticRegression(solver="lbfgs", max_iter=1000)
   ```
2. Call the cross_val_score with the parameters like model, selected_X, selected_Y, and cv:

   ```
   scores = cross_val_score(model, selected_X, selected_Y, cv=10)
   ```
3. Get the score's mean and std to see if the score is acceptable, if not, adjust model parameters in step 1. If yes, fit the model by calling:

   ```
   model.fit(selected_X, selected_Y)
   ```
4. Finally, use the model to predict data:

   ```
   predict_Y = model.predict(predict_X)
   ```

Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Comment: That said, your workflow is not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

Selecting model parameters via cross validation can e.g. be done with [hyper-parameter optimizers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#hyper-parameter-optimizers).